# MarkupExtension: changing constructor argument is not evaluated in design time

Tags: c#, wpf, markup-extensions, xaml-designer

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

When changing markup extension `Key` property - everything works.

When changing markup extension constructor argument - it's not updated. Workaround is to update property with extension (change `Text`) and then back. Then value is evaluated correctly.

Here is extension:

```
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public MyExtension() { }

    public MyExtension(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Key;
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how to make designer work with constructor argument same way as it does with property?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: @IlVic, didn't though it could be a VS bug. Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1. Tell me please if it works correctly for you.

Comment: You MarkupExtension works perfectly - for example - with Visual Studio 2010 Premium Edition (version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel). I can check with Visual Studio 2013 too, if you need. But I do not have Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @IlVic, are you sure? Try to change in xaml `{local:My 1}` -> `{local:My 123}` is rendered in designer window updated properly after each change? `{local:My Key=123}` works, but without `Key` when I try to change it stays for me unchanged. I tried to disable extensions, but the problem still.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I copied your `MyExtension` code then I built my solution. Then if I change `{local:My a}` in `{local:My abc}` then "abc" is immediately rendered in the XAML preview (or designer, as you prefer).

Comment: @IlVic, thanks. I am not sure what to do now. Looks like I am doomed to use extension with `Key`.

Comment: @Sinatr did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue with VS 2019

Comment: @MarkusHütter, nope. I am just using property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to remedy this situation is the use of `ConstructorArgumentAttribute` like so:

```
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public MyExtension() { }

    public MyExtension(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Key;
    }
}
```